# How to extract a text from a nested tag in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, beautifulsoup

I'm hoping to web scrape Google results, and want to get the first pieces of information that appear.  How do I specify a specific HTML path to extract text from?

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

city = "Potomac"
suffix = "Weather"
query = city + " " + suffix

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query

# Now have the best URL for a city
results = requests.get(url)

# Extract all content
src = results.content

# Get HTML soup of all content on that page
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
# print(soup.prettify())

# Try to find and print specific places
precip = soup.findAll("span", attrs = {"id": "wob_pp"})
```

I was expecting to find all span tags (which is the tag of the data I am trying to extract), however many of the nested span tags do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

You should request via HTTP Header.
HTTP headers allow the client and the server to pass additional information with the request or the response.

```
results = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'})
```